# For every $n$, $\sum\limits_{m=0}^{\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\sum\limits_{l=0}^m\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right)^{m-l} {n \choose l}=1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

> Show that for every $n$ we have that
>
> $$\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\sum_{l=0}^m\left(\left[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right]^{(m-l)}{n \choose l}  \right)\right]=1$$
>
> **Hint:** Represent the function
>
> $$F(x) =\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\left[x^m\sum_{l=0}^m\left(\left[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right]^{(m-l)}{n \choose l}  \right)\right]$$
>
> as the product of two generating functions.

I'm really stuck. We know that

$$1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} +... = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}} =\frac{2}{3}$$

So I thought it would be enough to show that $\forall m$

$$\sum_{l=0}^m\left(\left[\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right]^{(m-l)} {n \choose l}  \right) = \frac{3}{2}$$

But

1) I've had a hard time trying to show that the sum above has a constant value independent of $m$ (by transforming $2^{n-1}$ in a sum of binomial coefficients, and seeing if something gets cancelled out).

2) The hint confuses me. As noticed, I wasn't applying it in my only attempt, and at the same time I don't know how to take advantage of that fact.

Comment: Well, the hint is rather transparent, no? ...And I fail to understand why you prefer to run into a deadend rather than applying it? Anyway, you are told to notice that, by the change of variable $m=l+k$, $$F(x) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(n)^kx^k\cdot\sum_{l=0}^n{n\choose l}x^l$$ with $$a(n)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2$$ hence $$F(x) =\frac1{1-a(n)x}\cdot(1+x)^n$$ Now, for $x=-\frac12$, the first factor of the product is $2^n$ and the second is $\left(\frac12\right)^n$, hence $F\left(-\frac12\right)=1$, qed.

Comment: @Did Wow. What a simple way to tackle it (: Just one question: How from $\sum_{l=0}^{l+k}{n\choose l}x^l$ you go to $\sum_{l=0}^n{n\choose l}x^l$. That is, how did you assume that $k = n$? Can it be the case where $k \neq n$?. Thanks for shedding light on this.

Comment: @Did I think I got it. We have $m(k) = l + k$. As $m \to \infty$, $k \to \infty $ as well, but ${n\choose l} = 0$, $\forall\ l>n$ so it's enough to consider the rightmost summation till $k = n$ or $\sum_{l=0}^n{n\choose l}x^l$

Comment: There is no $\sum\limits_{l=0}^{l+k}$ involved (fortunately since the autoreference to $l$ would be absurd). Rather one starts from the double sum $$\sum_{0\leqslant l\leqslant m}$$ and the change of variable $m=l+k$ transforms it into the double sum $$\sum_{l\geqslant 0}\sum_{k\geqslant 0}$$ Finally, in the sum on $l\geqslant0$, only the terms with $l\leqslant n$ are nonzero, qed.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume we don't know any hint. A technique which is often helpful is *exchanging sums*.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{m=0}^\infty&\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\sum_{l=0}^m\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right)^{m-l}\binom{n}{l}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=l}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^m\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right)^{m-l}\binom{n}{l}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{n}{l}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{m+l}\left(\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}-2\right)^{m}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{l=0}^\infty\binom{n}{l}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{l}\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)^{m}\tag{3}\\
> &=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\frac{1}{1-\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)}\tag{4}\\
> &=1
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange the series by noting
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^m a_{m,l}=\sum_{0\leq l\leq m< \infty} a_{m,l}=
  \sum_{l=0}^\infty\sum_{m=l}^\infty a_{m,l}
  \end{align*}
- In (2) we shift the index $m$ of the inner sum by $l$ to start from $m=0$ and we do a small rearrangement.
- In (3) we simplify the expression and observe the double series is in fact a product of two series.
- In (4) we apply the formula for the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and for the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.